# Structural equivalence of two context-free grammars

Tags: complexity-classes, grammars, context-free

I understand that determining if two context-free grammars are structurally equivalent is decidable (according to the 1968 paper by Paull, M.C. and Unger, S.H., "Structural equivalence of context-free grammars"). I wonder what the best algorithm for this problem is, and what the computational complexity of the algorithm is. Thank you.

Comment: This was an open problem in the 1976 classic _On the equivalence, containment, and covering problems for the regular and context-free languages_ paper by Hunt, Rosenkrantz, and Szymanski (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(76)80038-4).  There is a paper titled _The complexity of structural containment and equivalence_ by Hunt and Rosenkrantz in a book dedicated to Ginsburg, _Theoretical studies in computer science_, Academic Press 1992, but I have never read it.